# Placing VSDocman external files on Sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010

I am wanting to generate all of our application documentation using [VSDocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) and put them on Sharepoint. The act of uploading the finished documentation to Sharepoint isn't an issue and can be done fairly easily. The issue I have however is that VSDocman will not let me embed images in to the documentation unless I have the `External Files Folder` property set in its settings.

I want to set this property to be a child-directory on the sharepoint server where I place the actual generated documentation. So if my path is `http://sharepointsite/documents/project1/docs`, I'd want to place the directory in `http://sharepointsite/docuemnts/project1/docs/images/`

I'm not sure how to do that with Sharepoint. I have not been able to find any documentation online on how to basically connect to that sharepoint directory using a network drive or something that i can point VSDocman to. Anyone have any experience with trying to map to a sharepoint drive, without using the sharepoint workspace syncing? I need to basically have a filepath to the directory for VSDocman to use explicitly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by mapping as a network drive using

```
\\sharepointsite\shared documents\project1\docs\images
```

In windows explorer. Once I figured out I could map to the drive, I just paste the same url in to VSDocman and attach the images that I needed. Worked like a charm.